# Why are box-shadow and margin not displaying correctly for a division of my code?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble adding box-shadow to my card divisions: nothing appears, regardless of the color I choose. Similarly, when I modify the margin of those divisions, it does not change anything in the result. When I open the file in Google Chrome, the inspector says "Invalid property value" for those two properties. I don't understand why this would be invalid.

Could somebody give me a hand? I am a beginner.

```
body{
    background-color: #23272A;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    font-weight:500;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(59, 255, 203,0.9);
    font-weight: 700;
}

a:hover{
    color:rgb(252, 148, 3);
}

h1,h2,h3{   
    color:#8EA1E1;
    font-family: "Alatsi",sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width:700px;
    margin:90px auto;
    padding:30px;
}

**.card-grey {
    background-color : #36393F; 
    margin:30px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px yellow;**
}

.img-circle {
    border-radius:50%;
}

.btn-purple{
    background-color:purple
}
```

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Profil de x</title>
        <meta name="Description" content="Bienvenue sur le profil de x, alias x"
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c21d0567d8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alatsi&family=Alegreya+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400&family=Nunito:wght@200;400;700&family=Teko:wght@300;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card-grey">
                <h1> BIENVENUE SUR LE PROFIL DE x </h1>
                <img class="img-circle" src="images/pp.jpg" alt="x photo">
                <p> Je m'appelle x bla bla
                </p>
                <a class="btn-purple" href="x">Checkez mon linkedin</a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-grey">
                <h2> Passion A </h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nisl orci, lobortis vel ex at, imperdiet pretium velit. Proin ultricies est id felis lacinia, id suscipit dui consequat. Aenean ut nunc vitae massa aliquam pulvinar. Maecenas laoreet ipsum et lectus ornare, eget maximus est pharetra. Phasellus quis magna fringilla dolor.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-grey">
                <h2> Passion B</h2>
                <p>xx
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-grey">
                <h2> Passion C </h2>
                <p>xx
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-grey">
                <h2> FOLLOW ME ! </h2>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>
                        <a href="x" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="x" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="x" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed 2 things, on line 4 of your .html file you didn't close the bracket on your name meta tag, the second thing is that you used a line break character on the background-color line, this might cause problems on your browser, if you're using VS Code you can check for unusual line terminators on `editor.unusualLineTerminators`, I tested your file fixing these and everything seems to be working fine on the box shadow property. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Un4.png)

Answer (score 1):

There was a weird `\u2028` character after the `background-color`'s value of your `.card-grey`.removing it solved the problem.
[image]

```css
body{
    background-color: #23272A;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    font-weight:500;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(59, 255, 203,0.9);
    font-weight: 700;
}

a:hover{
    color:rgb(252, 148, 3);
}

h1,h2,h3{   
    color:#8EA1E1;
    font-family: "Alatsi",sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width:700px;
    margin:90px auto;
    padding:30px;
}

.card-grey {
    background-color : #36393F;
    margin:5rem;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px yellow;
}

.img-circle {
    border-radius:50%;
}

.btn-purple{
    background-color:purple
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Profil de x</title>
        <meta name="Description" content="Bienvenue sur le profil de x, alias x"
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c21d0567d8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alatsi&family=Alegreya+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,400&family=Nunito:wght@200;400;700&family=Teko:wght@300;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card-grey">
                <h1> BIENVENUE SUR LE PROFIL DE x </h1>
                <img class="img-circle" src="images/pp.jpg" alt="x photo">
                <p> Je m'appelle x bla bla
                </p>
                <a class="btn-purple" href="x">Checkez mon linkedin</a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-grey">
                <h2> Passion A </h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nisl orci, lobortis vel ex at, imperdiet pretium velit. Proin ultricies est id felis lacinia, id suscipit dui consequat. Aenean ut nunc vitae massa aliquam pulvinar. Maecenas laoreet ipsum et lectus ornare, eget maximus est pharetra. Phasellus quis magna fringilla dolor.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-grey">
                <h2> Passion B</h2>
                <p>xx
                </p>
            </div>

    </body>
```